# What parameters are important when replacing a rear hub?

Tags: mountain-bike, repair, hub, shopping

My rear hub is damaged. I have not yet inspected the source of the damage, but the wheel is moving sideways when rotating (a LOT), plus I rode it like this for about 35km. Therefore, I find it probable to soon need to replace the hub.

The rim and spokes are new (couple of months of commuting). I suppose I wouldn't be running in the "old spokes new hub" problem.

The old hub has 24 spokes. The disc rotor is attacked via 6 bolts.

*What else should I know in order to judge if a specific hub will be a compatible swap* (beyond that getting the exact same hub should work okay).

Comment: Please clarify, the wheel is moving sideways in the dropouts or the wheel is not true (the wheel is doing like a figure 8 as seen head-on). If there are no snapped/loose spokes but the wheel is not spinning true, then maybe you are overloading it.

Answer (score 2):

You need the:

- right width to match the dropouts you are fitting the wheel to (135 mm for rear hubs, 100mm for front typically).
- same number of spokes as the rim you intend to use.
- the right brake rotor mounting (center lock or 6 bolt).
- the right axle width, diameter and fastening for the dropout (bolt thru, butted axle, quick release or thru axle (eg. maxle / maxle lite).

Putting the wheel together is a whole different matter, and there are tons of questions on wheel building here as well as entire books (like Brandt's The Bicycle Wheel).

As for 24 spokes, I'm not sure I'd be comfortable with a 24 spoke wheel in most cases.

Comment: So no "hub flange diameter" and angles and lengths and moon phase?

Comment: Hub flange diameter can matter because it will affect the spoke length you need, so if you want to use the same spokes that you already have you'll need to pay attention to that.

Comment: If the wheel used any proprietary tech then you may need to do a straight swap. Fulcrum mtb wheels and the 2:1 spoke ratio is an example.

Comment: @Vorac, hub flange diameter shouldn't be an issue, since IMHO re-using spokes is a __really__ bad idea.